# задать дополнительний язык через cmd

Tags: windows-7, cmd

Проблема следующая: мне нужно временно в мою расскладку включать дополнительний язык (например, германский). Я хочу создать батник, забиндить его на клавиатуру.

Вопрос: как с помощью cmd можно прописать конфигурацию для добавления дополнительного языка в языковую панель, а потом удалять? Спасибо.

Нашел только эти примеры, но там есть настройки по смене языка

```
intlcfg.exe [-all:language_name] [-uilang:language_name] [-uilangfallback:language_name] [-syslocale:language_name][-userlocale:language_name] [-inputlocale:default_keyboard_description; keyboard_description or locale_name] [-userhive:registry_path] [-syshive:registry_path] [-swhive:registry_path] [-image:path] [-dist:path] [-silent] [-skudefaults:language]
Update the lang.ini file and set the default language
intlcfg.exe -genlangini:filename [-defaultlang:language] [-dist:path -image:path] [-f]
Report the languages and language settings
intlcfg  -report [-dist:path] [-image:path]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[См. MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/goglobal/bb964650). Речь там про Висту, но работает и в Win7.

В общих чертах: для добавления раскладки создайте XML-файл примерно такого вида:

```xml
<gs:GlobalizationServices xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend">
    <gs:UserList>
        <gs:User UserID="Current"/> 
    </gs:UserList>
    <gs:InputPreferences> 
        <!-- 0407 - код немецкого языка -->
        <gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="0407:00000407"/> 
    </gs:InputPreferences> 
</gs:GlobalizationServices>
```

После чего в CMD можно будет написать команду:

```
control intl.cpl,, /f:"<имя вашего файла>"
```

Для удаления раскладки, создаете аналогичный файл, заменив в нем

```xml
Action="add"
```

на

```xml
Action="remove"
```

и вызываете аналогичным образом.

Comment: Спасибо, работает